# Any way to reliably get manics to spawn after U 17?

Tags: warframe

Ash is the only warframe (of those available) that I don't have.  For the life of me I haven't been able to get manics to reliably spawn.  Some have suggested LOR, but it seems a bit much to try and farm manics. I have tried various sabotage, exterminate and survival missions in the mid to high level Grineer controlled worlds, all to no avail.  Anyone have ideas for reliably farming Ash part blueprints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I know how Manics are summoned is a period of time after the alarm been raised, which includes defenses, survivals & interceptions. DE seems to prolonged this period after U17.

I've thought of two ways:

1. Raise the alarm and hide in a corner, on top of a ledge, or anywhere far away from enemy fire. Then turn up your volume and go AFK (but not away from your computer), have a break & relax but be aware of Manic's laughter.
2. Join a (Law of Retribution) raid/trial squad, there are relatively more Manics there. If possible, go with as many of your friends as possible to farm them.

Comment: The Law of Retribution raid is the way to go.  I've gotten into a group and done the raid 5 times now.  Of the 5 times I have done it, I have gotten a complete Ash set 4 of those times.